# Identify Missing Variable & create dummy rows - Range based

Tags: python, pandas

Input DataFrame

```
input_df = pd.DataFrame({'RegistrationNumber':['HY12TN2345', 'HY12TN2345','HY12TN2345',
    'JO78UI4675','JO78UI4675','JO78UI4675'],
    'KMServiceDone' : [10000,20000,50000,210000,230000,250000]})
print(input)
```

Output Required - Last Column i.e.StatusAvailed

```
output = pd.DataFrame({'RegistrationNumber':['HY12TN2345', 'HY12TN2345','HY12TN2345',
    'HY12TN2345', 'HY12TN2345', 'JO78UI4675','JO78UI4675','JO78UI4675',
    'HY12TN2345', 'HY12TN2345'],
    'KMServiceDone' : [10000,20000,30000,40000,50000,210000,
                       220000,230000,240000,250000],
    'StatusAvailed':['Availed', 'Availed', 'Missed', 'Missed', 'Availed',
                     'Availed', 'Missed', 'Availed', 'Missed', 'Availed']})
print(output)
```

What I tried

```
# get all possible values
all_services = df['KMServiceDone'].unique()

def reindex_grp(grp):
    s = grp.set_index('KMServiceDone')
    # add dummy rows for missing KMServiceDone
    s = s.reindex(all_services)
    return s.reset_index()

# apply function on each group
dfx = (df
  .groupby('RegistrationNumber', as_index=False)
  .apply(reindex_grp)
  .reset_index(drop=True))

# create status column
dfx['StatusAvailed'] = np.where(dfx['RegistrationNumber'].isna(),
                             'Missed', 
                             'Availed')
```

But not getting the desired output. Any inputs pls.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to generate a range of missing numbers:

```
delta = 10000

df = (df.assign(Status="Availed")
        .set_index("KMServiceDone")
        .groupby("RegistrationNumber")["Status"]
        .apply(lambda d: d.reindex(np.arange(min(d.index), max(d.index)+delta, delta)))
        .reset_index()
        .fillna("Missed"))

print (df)

  RegistrationNumber  KMServiceDone   Status
0         HY12TN2345          10000  Availed
1         HY12TN2345          20000  Availed
2         HY12TN2345          30000   Missed
3         HY12TN2345          40000   Missed
4         HY12TN2345          50000  Availed
5         JO78UI4675         210000  Availed
6         JO78UI4675         220000   Missed
7         JO78UI4675         230000  Availed
8         JO78UI4675         240000   Missed
9         JO78UI4675         250000  Availed
```